# How to avoid incorrect total order amount when using Criteria.addAssociation in Shopware6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using `Criteria.addAggregation` for getting sum of amount total but when I use `critaria.addAssociation('lineItems.product')`, it duplicates order data because of left join. As a result, it gives incorrect total order amount.

Shopware doing this;

```sql
SELECT SUM(`order`.`amount_total`) as `orderAmountTotal`
FROM `order`
         LEFT JOIN `document` `order.documents` ON `order`.`id` = `order.documents`.`order_id`
         LEFT JOIN `document_type` `order.documents.documentType`
                   ON `order.documents`.`document_type_id` = `order.documents.documentType`.`id`
WHERE (`order`.`version_id` = 0x0FA91CE3E96A4BC2BE4BD9CE752C3425)
  AND (((`order.documents.documentType`.`technical_name` = 'invoice' AND
         (`order.documents`.`created_at` >= '2022-05-31T22:00:00.852Z' AND
          `order.documents`.`created_at` <= '2023-06-01T10:04:08.852Z'))));
```

What I want;

```sql
SELECT SUM(`order`.`amount_total`) as `orderAmountTotal`
FROM (SELECT `order`.`amount_total`
      FROM `order`
               LEFT JOIN `document` `order.documents` ON `order`.`id` = `order.documents`.`order_id`
               LEFT JOIN `document_type` `order.documents.documentType`
                         ON `order.documents`.`document_type_id` = `order.documents.documentType`.`id`
      WHERE (`order`.`version_id` = 0x0FA91CE3E96A4BC2BE4BD9CE752C3425)
        AND (((`order.documents.documentType`.`technical_name` = 'invoice' AND
               (`order.documents`.`created_at` >= '2022-05-31T22:00:00.852Z' AND
                `order.documents`.`created_at` <= '2023-06-01T10:04:08.852Z'))))
      GROUP BY `order`.`id`) `order`;
```

Do I have to write own controller for this process? Is there any other way? I want to deal with one criteria but I couldn't get it done.

Aggregation and Association that I used in overridden sw-order-list

```js
orderCriteria() {
    const defaultCriteria = this.$super('orderCriteria');
    defaultCriteria.addAssociation('documents.documentType');
    defaultCriteria.addAggregation(Criteria.sum('orderAmountTotal', 'amountTotal'));
    return defaultCriteria;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` type aggregation currently isn't capable of dealing with this kind of nested aggregations, something that would have to be implemented to yield a sub-query like that. So, no, currently this can't be achieved using the database abstraction layer API.